# Using Dotnet and MSBuild tools in Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker

I am trying to build an ASP.net MVC project in a dockerfile in order to run in a container.

I tried using both the dotnet image and the servercore image
in different dockerfiles whilst then using chocolately to install the other missing package and trying to build with msbuild but I'm stuck.

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1480
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'; $ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR /appdir
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY . /appdir/
COPY /ExFin.Web/packages.config /appdir/

ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression 'true'
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
RUN choco install visualstudio2019buildtools -y;
RUN choco install dotnet4.5.2 -Force -y;
RUN choco install nuget.commandline --pre 

ENV NUGET_PATH "C:\Chocolatey\lib\NuGet.CommandLine.3.5.0\tools"
ENV MSBUILD_PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"

RUN $env:PATH = $env:NUGET_PATH + ';' + $env:MSBUILD_PATH + ';' + $env:PATH; `
RUN [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

RUN nuget.exe restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory /appdir/packages/
RUN ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe", "C:/appdir/ExFin.Web/ExFin.Web.csproj"]
```

The error:
Failures

- dotnetfx (exited -1073741502) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\dotnetfx\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
  See log for details.
- visualstudio2019buildtools (exited -1073741502) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019buildtools\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
  See log for details.

Could this mean that a restart is required??

Answer (score 3):

Use Microsoft's [.NET Framework SDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/) ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/3aee45752787b04c992f3d4c2cf7e4c037ca834f/src/sdk/4.8/windowsservercore-2004/Dockerfile)) image based on [.NET Framework Runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/) based on Windows Server Core.

The image includes:

1. .NET Framework Runtime
2. Visual Studio Build Tools
3. Visual Studio Test Agent
4. NuGet CLI
5. .NET Framework Targeting Packs
6. ASP.NET Web Targets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) to install MSBuild tools 2022.

```
choco install visualstudio2022buildtools
```

Also, Microsoft has an example Dockerfile which manually installs build tools 2022.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022#create-and-build-the-dockerfile

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2022 image.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `
    # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
    curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe `
    `
    # Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
    && (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```