# Docker file with .net6 and msbuild

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild

I need to run to some of my tests, which have Microsoft Fakes, via Docker. Since the `dotnet` command does not work with Fakes, I need to install and run `msbuild` in DockerFile. My project is based on .NET6. I see this can be done for the dotnet framework as shown here
: [Using Dotnet and MSBuild tools in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934103/using-dotnet-and-msbuild-tools-in-dockerfile), but is there is an easy way to do this in .NET6 without having to download and install Visual Studio Build Tools.

Comment: Unlike `dotnet`, `msbuild` itself can't run unit tests. It needs to invoke a test runner. You need the `VSTest.Console.exe` tool and, for Fakes, a Visual Studio Enterprise license. It appears that the Enterprise license or an equivalent is not supported for the Visual Studio Build Tools. To run Microsoft Fakes you need a full Visual Studio Enterprise install.